# How to insert values in database using function in java servlet and jsp

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, servlets

I am trying to add, update and delete using function but value is not inserted. 
please help me for this. the value does not insert into database it gives error
in database values is not insert after saving the records
i have tried following code

```
package main;

import java.sql.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 *
 * @author abc
 */
public class TenantOperation {

    private Connection conn;

    public TenantOperation()
    {
        conn = ConnectionDb.getConnection();
    }

    public void addTenant(TenantClass tenantclass) {
        try {
            String sql = "INSERT INTO tenantmaster(flatno,ownername,contactno,flattype,buildingname) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
            PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);

            ps.setInt(1, tenantclass.getFlatno());
            ps.setString(2, tenantclass.getOwnername());
            ps.setString(3, tenantclass.getMob());            
            ps.setString(4, tenantclass.getFlattype());
            ps.setString(5, tenantclass.getBuildingname());
                    ps.executeUpdate();

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

     public void removeTenant(int tenantId) {
        try {
            String sql = "DELETE FROM tenantmaster WHERE tenantid=?";
            PreparedStatement ps = conn
                    .prepareStatement(sql);
            ps.setInt(1, tenantId);
            ps.executeUpdate();

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
      }


Here I have accessed that addtenant(). i have connect that function in this class


package main;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 *
 * @author abc
 */
public class TenantHandler extends HttpServlet {
     private static String insert= "/tenantadd.jsp";
    private static String Edit = "/tenantadd.jsp";
    private static String TenantRecords = "/tenantadd.jsp";
    private TenantOperation tenantOperation;

    public TenantHandler()
    {   
        super();
     tenantOperation = new TenantOperation();
    }



    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        String redirect="";
        String flatno = request.getParameter("flatno");        
        String action = request.getParameter("action");

         if(action.equalsIgnoreCase("insert"))
        {   
            int no = Integer.parseInt(flatno);

            TenantClass tenantclass = new TenantClass();
            tenantclass.setFlatno(no);
            tenantclass.setOwnername(request.getParameter("ownername"));
             tenantclass.setMob(request.getParameter("mob"));
              tenantclass.setFlattype(request.getParameter("flattype"));
             tenantclass.setBuildingname(request.getParameter("buildingname"));


            tenantOperation.addTenant(tenantclass);
            redirect = TenantRecords;
               // request.setAttribute("tenantList", tenantOperation.getAllTenants());
            //System.out.println("Record Added Successfully");
        }


    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

    }  
    @Override
    public String getServletInfo() {
        return "Short description";
    }// </editor-fold>

}
```

Comment: What is the stacktrace?...

Comment: it didnt display anything

Comment: Is your connection set to auto-commit, or is there an explicit commit somewhere?

Comment: server logs,any exceptions thrown?